# Getting error running maven image through packer build

Tags: maven, docker, continuous-integration, packer

While running maven image through packer for building purpose I am getting bellow error .

> ```
> docker: Run command: docker run -v /root/.packer.d/tmp904651335:/packer-files -d -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/sh -- maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine
> ```
>
> ==> docker: Error running container: Docker exited with a non-zero exit status.
>   ==> docker: Stderr: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 0 caused \\"error running hook: exit status 2, stdout: , stderr: fatal error: runtime: out of memory\\n\\nruntime stack:\\nruntime.throw(0x55f4917c6982, 0x16)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x74 fp=0x7ffddd5eeda0 sp=0x7ffddd5eed70 pc=0x55f48fe87e74\\nruntime.sysMap(0xc000000000, 0x4000000, 0x55f493cd53d8)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:170 +0xc9 fp=0x7ffddd5eede0 sp=0x7ffddd5eeda0 pc=0x55f48fe723b9\\nruntime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x55f493cb89c0, 0x2000, 0x55f493cb89d0, 0x1)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:633 +0x1cf fp=0x7ffddd5eee88 sp=0x7ffddd5eede0 pc=0x55f48fe6525f\\nruntime.(*mheap).grow(0x55f493cb89c0, 0x1, 0x0)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1222 +0x44 fp=0x7ffddd5eeee0 sp=0x7ffddd5eee88 pc=0x55f48fe7f7c4\\nruntime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x55f493cb89c0, 0x1, 0x55f493cd53e8, 0x0)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1150 +0x381 fp=0x7ffddd5eef18 sp=0x7ffddd5eeee0 pc=0x55f48fe7f6b1\\nruntime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x55f493cb89c0, 0x1, 0x2a, 0x6e43a318)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:977 +0xc6 fp=0x7ffddd5eef68 sp=0x7ffddd5eef18 pc=0x55f48fe7ed06\\nruntime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1048 +0x4e fp=0x7ffddd5eefa0 sp=0x7ffddd5eef68 pc=0x55f48feb3ace\\nruntime.(*mheap).alloc(0x55f493cb89c0, 0x1, 0x55f48f01002a, 0x7ffddd5ef040)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1047 +0x8c fp=0x7ffddd5eeff0 sp=0x7ffddd5eefa0 pc=0x55f48fe7efdc\\nruntime.(*mcentral).grow(0x55f493cb97c0, 0x0)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:256 +0x97 fp=0x7ffddd5ef038 sp=0x7ffddd5eeff0 pc=0x55f48fe71e37\\nruntime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x55f493cb97c0, 0x7fd212eef000)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:106 +0x301 fp=0x7ffddd5ef098 sp=0x7ffddd5ef038 pc=0x55f48fe71941\\nruntime.(*mcache).refill(0x7fd212eef008, 0x2a)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:135 +0x88 fp=0x7ffddd5ef0b8 sp=0x7ffddd5ef098 pc=0x55f48fe713d8\\nruntime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x7fd212eef008, 0x55f493cae12a, 0x7fd212eef008, 0x7fd212eef000, 0x8)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:786 +0x8a fp=0x7ffddd5ef0f0 sp=0x7ffddd5ef0b8 pc=0x55f48fe65a9a\\nruntime.mallocgc(0x180, 0x55f492810d80, 0x1, 0x55f493cd5440)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:939 +0x780 fp=0x7ffddd5ef190 sp=0x7ffddd5ef0f0 pc=0x55f48fe663d0\\nruntime.newobject(0x55f492810d80, 0x4000)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1068 +0x3a fp=0x7ffddd5ef1c0 sp=0x7ffddd5ef190 pc=0x55f48fe667da\\nruntime.malg(0x32100008000, 0x55f493cbb030)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:3220 +0x33 fp=0x7ffddd5ef200 sp=0x7ffddd5ef1c0 pc=0x55f48fe91323\\nruntime.mpreinit(...)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:311\\nruntime.mcommoninit(0x55f493cb3480)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:618 +0xc6 fp=0x7ffddd5ef238 sp=0x7ffddd5ef200 pc=0x55f48fe8ac96\\nruntime.schedinit()\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:540 +0x78 fp=0x7ffddd5ef290 sp=0x7ffddd5ef238 pc=0x55f48fe8a928\\nruntime.rt0_go(0x7ffddd5ef398, 0x4, 0x7ffddd5ef398, 0x0, 0x7fd21218e2e1, 0x4, 0x7ffddd5ef398, 0x41107e000, 0x55f48feb5bb0, 0x0, ...)\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:195 +0x11e fp=0x7ffddd5ef298 sp=0x7ffddd5ef290 pc=0x55f48feb5cde\\n\\"\"": unknown.

I am using bellow packer code for building .

```
 {
  "builders": [{
    "type": "docker",
    "image": "maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim",
    "commit": "true",
    "changes": [
    "WORKDIR /",
    "CMD [\"mvn package\"]",
    "CMD [\"mv target/SpringExample-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar\"]",
    "ENTRYPOINT [\"docker-entrypoint.sh\"]"
  ]
  }],
  "provisioners": [
    {
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": ["mkdir -p /src"]
    },
    {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "src/",
    "destination": "/src/"
    },
    {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "pom.xml",
    "destination": "/"
    },
    {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "destination": "/"
    }

   ],
  "post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "satwikmukherjee/####",
        "tag": "maven1.0"
      },
      {
        "type": "docker-push",
        "login": "true",
        "login_username": "#####",
        "login_password": "####"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says:

`error running hook: exit status 2, stdout: , stderr: fatal error: runtime: out of memory`